# How to properly implement loading message on data submission or fetching in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

The code below successfully fetch data from my Atlassian instance using Reactjs.

Now I want to be able to display a loading message that will be display and data is being submitted or fetched but cannot get it to work.

I have initialized

```
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
setLoading(true);
```

Where do I add  `setLoading(false);`? Or is there another better solution?

Here is the code:

**app.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from "react";

function App() {

const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
//invoke('postdata').then(setData);

setLoading(true);
const dx = {uid: 'NancyMoore'};
 invoke('postdata', dx).then(setData);


}, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2> Submited Data</h2>
       
{JSON.stringify(data)}

{loading && <span> data is being submitted  ...</span>}


    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import Resolver from '@forge/resolver';
const resolver = new Resolver();

resolver.define('postdata', async (req) => { 
const datax = await storage.set('my-key');
console.log(datax);
return datax;

});

export const handler = resolver.getDefinitions();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite simple, you want to set the loading **after** you get a response from the server, whatever it may be.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // start loader
  setLoading(true);
  const dx = {uid: 'NancyMoore'};
  
  // make request
  invoke('postdata', dx)
  .then((response) => {
     setData(response);

     // data is fetched, stop loader
     setLoading(false);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // error handling
    console.error(error);

    // here you may stop loader if you need to, but it's optional
    setLoading(false);
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Hi ! 

I'd suggest using a try-catch statement, since you can set the loading state to `true` inside the `try` statement, fetch the data. Inside the `catch` statement you can handle errors and in the `finally` statement you can set the loading state back to `false`. 

So regardless if there is an error or not, after running the code the loading state is always set to false.